# How to access this kind of array value?

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

I scraped Twitter media with `simple_html_dom` and got this array result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DWyUfBdVwAE9bmJ.jpg
    [1] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DWyUgBUVMAASB_g.jpg
    [2] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DWyUg-xU0AEHdyL.jpg
)
Array
(
    [0] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CYba_z2UwAAoSuC.jpg
)
Array
(
    [0] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CTyJ52dUEAAirWw.jpg
    [1] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CTyJ5yMUkAAbvZq.jpg
    [2] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CTyJ5k4VEAAC4f7.jpg
    [3] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CTyJ5f4VAAAZ08g.jpg
)
Array
(
    [0] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CTyJJyeUcAAo8kt.jpg
    [1] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CTyJJ2KUkAIKOPa.jpg
    [2] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CTyJJycUkAAL29J.jpg
)
```

How can I access every `$value[0]` for each array?

this is my code based on https://github.com/alexroan/twitter-scraper :

```
    <?php
  require 'TwitterScraper.php';
    $feed = TwitterScraper::get_feed('maretaso_u');
    foreach($feed as $tweet){ 

        $media = $tweet->media;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($media);   
        echo "<pre>";

    }
```

Comment: Is the entire result an array inside which there are 4 arrays?

Comment: If you paste the code that collects the data it should be easy to help you.

Comment: actually i did it with the scrapper here 
@AlexPerrin https://github.com/alexroan/twitter-scraper

Comment: Show us the code that got you that output above.

Comment: If you have used this line of code: $feed = Twitter_Scraper::get_feed('toto'); Can you do a print_r($feed); ?

Comment: @IncredibleHat already edited my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make some guesses based on the info you gave. But this is what I did:

```
<?php

$feed = TwitterScraper::get_feed('maretaso_u');

$filtered = array_map(function($tweet) {
    return $tweet->media[0];
}, $feed);

var_dump($filtered);
```

Comment: i tried it and it just return the "h" character for each array element :/

Comment: You can remove the foreach loop. You just added your code so I know now how you can implement it

Comment: i need the foreach to get access to twitter media $media = $tweet->media; based on this example https://github.com/alexroan/twitter-scraper

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish. A certain datastructure? Or do you want to store them in a database?

Comment: a certain datastructure so i can access every $values[0] from every array

Comment: The `$filtered` variable is now a list of all first items in the `media` attribute. That is what you want right?

Comment: $tweet->media still need to do a foreach to get the array result i got like in the questions

Comment: You didn't want the array result in your question. You only wanted the first one from each list right?

Comment: i did it with your code and add the foreach and somehow it works http://prntscr.com/itcshg

Comment: Can you send me the code snippet? On pastebin or something. I also need a var_dump of the full feed to understand this

Comment: but in my case there is an empty value in the array,  how to skip it? here is the script https://pastebin.com/Thf4DXgB

Comment: never mind i just skip the empty value with array_filter haahaha thank you very much!

Comment: The `foreach` statement is empty. You can simply remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
$filtered = [];

foreach ($list as $values) {
    $filtered[] = $values[0];
}

var_dump($filtered);
```

Comment: What about `array_map`?

Comment: ´array_map´ has the overhead of a function call for each element in the array, so it will be (up to 5 times) slower then ´foreach´. array_map has issues with  scoping of variables etc...